# JBoss EAP 6.2 high availability without HTTP server

Tags: windows, high-availability, jboss, eap

i'm looking for some solution to make a Jboss Cluster ( 2 nodes ) in H.A. ( 1 live, 1 backup) but i don't want to use a third element ( machine, service or whatever ).

Most configuration I found uses N nodes and 1 http server as dispatcher, but what i'm looking is something that no have "the critical point". I mean, if the dispatcher crash the entire system will be unavaiable and it's exactly what i dont want.

What would be the possibile solution on Windows 2012 R2?

Comment: A load balancer (within an H.A cluster too) would be, IMHO, the best design. However you could consider [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org)

Comment: @krisFR could be interesting, bu env is Windows !

Comment: On Windows you have [NLB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725691.aspx)

Comment: Oh, it would be great if you edit your post informing you are using windows :) (even better also use a tag and specify Windows version)